# Cómo hago que al introducir -1 me muestre el número menor sin contar el -1 en java

Tags: java

Al introducir `-1` me muestra que el número menor es `-1` pero me debería mostrar el número menor introducido sin incluirlo.

Lo he estado probando y el mayor sí me lo hace bien.

```
int edadAlumnos=0;
int menor=0;
int mayor=0;
   
do {    
    if (edadAlumnos<menor) {
        menor = edadAlumnos;
    }
    
    if (edadAlumnos>mayor) {
        mayor= edadAlumnos;
    }
    System.out.print("Dime la edad de el alumno: ");
    edadAlumnos = sc.nextInt();
} while (edadAlumnos!= -1);

System.out.println("El numero mayor es: "+mayor+" y el menor: "+menor);
```

Comment: Y si cambias el Do While,  por un While??

Comment: Me sigue contando el -1 como numero pero gracias por la aportacion

Comment: Algo estarás haciendo mal, porque debería darte cero si lo cambias por un while. Con lo cual te darías cuenta del otro problema que tiene tu código

Comment: Si, perdona, me da 0 en cambio si escribo un numero mayor que -5 si que me dice que el menor es -5 pero no deja con numeros positivos

Comment: Claro, porque tienes un problema de forma en tu ejercicio. Si necesitas número positivos y negativos, La parada de while no debería ser -1. Ahora si explícitamente son todos los números positivos y negativos exceptuando el -1, basta que en tu "if" los excluyas ( edadAlumno!=-1 && ....). Luego tienes tu segundo problema, es que las variables menor y mayor no debes inicializarlas en cero

Comment: No lo entiendo bien

Comment: EN ninguna parte de tu do-while estás validando si es `-1` ANTES de modificar los valores menor y mayor. Va a hacer toda la iteración y DESPUÉS va a parar. ENtonces, ponle un IF antes de los otros dos y si es `-1`, haces break.

Comment: Lo que trato de decirte es que tienes 2 problemas. 1) El -1 ¿Es o no un número valido como entrada? y 2) Que no puedes poner int menor=0, que pasa si yo ingreso 1,2,3y4 ??? el menor sigue siendo cero.- Mismo caso para el mayor=0, y si permites número negativos